# How to ignore warnings using ant mxmlc compiler

Tags: apache-flex, ant, mxmlc

I am using the ant mxmlc task to build my project. I wish to ignore compiler warnings generated using the flex sdk, using ant mxmlc task. What do I need to do to my build script to get these ignored?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add warnings="false"

example:

```
<mxmlc file="${SRC_DIR}/MainApplication.mxml" output="${OUTPUT_DIR}/MainApplication.swf' link-report="report.xml" compiler.optimize="true" keep-generated-actionscript="false" warnings="false" debug="false" strict="true" benchmark="true">
```